# Font is not display in mobile view or responsive view same as desktop view

Tags: html, css, mobile, blogger

I have problem with my mobile template. I am using custom template in my blog which come together with its mobile template. So I must disable in mobile theme setting  to make it exactly like desktop version. The font type in desktop version is perfect but in mobile template, the post title and post content not change like the desktop version. There are also widget not appear properly. This is my blog url : https://annaterritory.blogspot.com/ 
I am not good in coding. Sorry for my english. Thank you.

Updated: Just now I view mobile version on other android device. The template quite good but still not same as desktop version.

Answer (score 0):

**try @media query**   or `vw/vh` in your font-size

```
@media screen and (max-width: 779px) {
    body {
        font-size: your font size;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 780px) {
    body {
        font-size: your font size;
    }
}
```

or change use fontsize unit into **vh** or `vw` it will be responsive based on screen size...

try this [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)